# Split the page into different sections

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I am new to TikZ package. I am trying to split some LaTeX pages to different sections. In each section I want to be able write a text and draw simple Tikz figures(such as lines`\draw (0,0) -- (4,0);`) and apply different styles in each section (text color, background color). The first page should be in landscape position and should contain 2 sections. The second page should be in normal(portrait) position and contain 4 sections.
[image: This page contains 2 sections]
[image: This page contains 4 sections]

So far I got just the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Turn off page numeration

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=0.1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-15.2cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.2cm,1.2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{landscape}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
\end{landscape}
\newpage
second page
\end{document}
```

And I have no idea how to advance with that. Any suggestion? Should I still try to use TikZ or should I try something else? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little more detailed?

Comment: I don't understand why you're adding the picture to shipout or using `overlay, remember picture`, since you seem to want the picture to occupy space on the page.

Comment: current_user I have a PDF of scanned documents of following format and I have to translate them on other languages. But these docs are just a images, so I decided to make the same style in Latex (and probably to use it if the future as a template to translate them on few more languages.

Comment: cfr I don't know neither :) I am new on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to easily mix landscape and portrait pages on same document. `geometry` package allows to change text dimensions but not paper size or page orientation, therefore I propose to define landscape pages in one document and include them in main one with `pdfpages` help.

The pages design can be done with other packages, but I propose to use `tcolorbox` and its `tcbposter` tool. It allows to define flexible boxed distributions on a page.

The horizontal page is done with:

```
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=2, rows=1}
]
\posterbox{name=left, column=1, row=1}{\lipsum[1-3]}
\posterbox{name=right, column=2, row=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
```

This is a poster which will spread over the whole page formed by two equal columns. The style is the dafult from tcolorbox, but you can change as you like. The result looks like:

[image]

For the portrait page, I've also defined a `tcbposter` with five columns but left text will use three of them, while the right one will use the other two. Left and right black parts are drawn as `overlay`. The code for this poster is:

```
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=5, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[left=12mm, enhanced, 
     overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
         node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]
         {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} ([xshift=9mm]frame.south west);} 
]{name=left, column=1, span=3, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\posterbox[right=12mm, enhanced, 
      overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]
          {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=right, column=4, span=2, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
```

[image]

The complete code for both files is:

```
%landscape pages
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=2, rows=1}
]
\posterbox{name=left, column=1, row=1}{\lipsum[1-3]}
\posterbox{name=right, column=2, row=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

and the main file with portrait pages and including landscape through `includepdf`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %shows landscape pages in landscape

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\includepdf[landscape]{445940b}
\end{landscape}

\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=5, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[left=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=9mm]frame.south west);} 
]{name=left, column=1, span=3, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\posterbox[right=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=right, column=4, span=2, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ignasi thanks a lot. It works perfect for me. Cheers ;)