# Divide a page into independent columns with tcbposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, columns

I got an excellent answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445940/split-the-page-into-different-sections) (how to divide a page into 2 columns) but a new obstacle has come. Now I need to divide it to 1 single column) and 3 columns.
So far (thanks to [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi)) I have the following document:

[image]

with following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=5, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[left=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=9mm]frame.south west);} 
]{name=left, column=1, span=3, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\posterbox[right=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=right, column=4, span=2, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do now is to get the following:

1) A single column:

[image]

2) Tree equal columns *(On this image they don't look equal but it's because I just draw them on Paint)*

[image]

I was playing around with this code for a long time but I got just a mes but not the expected results. 
Could someone help me with it? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what the actual output should look like. Shall the columns be on one page (one column first and then three columns a little bit farther down) or shall the three-column style start on a second page?

Comment: I apologize for the screenshots guys! I was playing with thumbnail and them got extremely small. I will change it now

Comment: Hi, TeXnician. Sorry for these small previews. I already changed it. Yes, it should be 2 different page. I just wonder to figure out what should I change in the code to create single(3-column) styles.

Comment: @TeXnician, I was trying to change these values. But the problem was that the leftmost and the rightmost sections (the grey ones) got misaligned because of these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt that relies on strange – manually computed – values to shift the poster into the right position:

[image: strange poster]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=5, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[left=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=9mm]frame.south west);} 
]{name=left, column=1, span=3, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\posterbox[right=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=right, column=4, span=2, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = {spread, left=12.5mm},
    poster = {columns=3, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm, width=\dimexpr\linewidth-9.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[enhanced,
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south west);} 
]{name=left, column=1, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\posterbox{name=center, column=2, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\posterbox[enhanced,
          overlay={\fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=right, column=3, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

---

Update: I thought you would get the one-column thing by playing around with the option keys, but here is a code sample:

```
\begin{tcbposter}[%
    coverage = spread,
    poster = {columns=1, rows=1, spacing=-.5mm},
    boxes={sharp corners, colback=white}
]
\posterbox[left=12mm, right=12mm, enhanced, 
          overlay={
          \fill[black!70] (frame.north west) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=90]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=9mm]frame.south west);
          \fill[black!70] (frame.north east) rectangle 
          node[font=\sffamily\bfseries,text=white,rotate=270]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} 
          ([xshift=-9mm]frame.south east);} 
]{name=left, column=1, rowspan=1}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{tcbposter}
```

Comment: thanks, this works great. But how can I make a singles column document? (second screenshot on my question)

Comment: @Alex See my update.

Comment: you are right. I should make my questions clearer next time. Your Update works just great as well. Thanks for your help and have a great weekend!